Is dunder an official designation for `__method__` in Python?
In a Python class you can use methods whose name is preceded and followed by a double underscore, which are called by a "special" syntax which is not the usual object.method() syntax.
For example:
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

i = Item("car")

Here the Item("car") syntax will call the __init__ method.
Such methods are called "methods with special names" or "special method" by the Python documentation.
However, some sources on the web call these kind of methods "dunder methods" (source 1, source 2).
Is this designation of "dunder methods" an official Python name for these kind of methods?

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers tell us that dunder is informal name.

Why the downvote? It's a legitimate programming question.

Yes. I think it is a thing we should know. Part of programming is also documenting and explaining to other, and so a precise terminology is important (else just confuse people and makes learning a slower process).

@GiacomoCatenazzi can you convert your comment in an answer?

dunder is an abbreviation for "double underscore" - this is in reference to the double underscore on either side of the method that Python uses to denote a special method. It is therefore used by people synonymously with special method. Does this answer the question?
